# Is it possible to get query string before stored procedure execution in EF?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Is it possible to get query that entity framework generated for stored procedure before execution?
E.g. calling sp

`context.Test(1)`

and get the string

> exec [dbo].Test 1

but **before** execution

Comment: Which EF version do you use?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki  6

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Entity Framework 6, then you can use **Query Interceptors** to inject code between SQL generation and SQL execution. It is done by implementing `IDbInterceptor`. You can attach to the following "events":

```
namespace System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception
{
  public interface IDbCommandInterceptor : IDbInterceptor
  {
    void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext);

    void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext);

    void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext);

    void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext);

    void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext);

    void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext);
  }
}
```

You can write custom interceptor implmenting the interface above and then add it into your EF by calling:

`DbInterception.Add(new <your implementation>());`

There are also other suggestions of viewing the SQL generated by Entity Framework here: [How do I view the SQL generated by the Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework), but it depends whether you want to just view the SQL or to perform some actions before it is executed.

Comment: ok. thanks but it is possible to get query string modify it and then execute? so can I somehow stop execution by default